# Azure download blob part

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I would be very grateful if anybody has experience with the function DownloadRangeToStream.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadrangetostream%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) they say that the parameter "length" is the length of the data, but in my experience it is the upper position of the segment to download, e.g. "length" - "offset" = real length of the data.

I would also really appreciate if anybody could give me some code for downloading a blob in chunks, since the function mentioned before doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this code. It downloads a large blob by splitting it in 1 MB chunks.

```
    static void DownloadRangeExample()
    {
        var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        var containerName = "container";
        var blobName = "myfile.zip";
        int segmentSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;//1 MB chunk
        var blobContainer = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(containerName);
        var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        blob.FetchAttributes();
        var blobLengthRemaining = blob.Properties.Length;
        long startPosition = 0;
        string saveFileName = @"D:\myfile.zip";
        do
        {
            long blockSize = Math.Min(segmentSize, blobLengthRemaining);
            byte[] blobContents = new byte[blockSize];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                blob.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, startPosition, blockSize);
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Read(blobContents, 0, blobContents.Length);
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    fs.Position = startPosition;
                    fs.Write(blobContents, 0, blobContents.Length);
                }
            }
            startPosition += blockSize;
            blobLengthRemaining -= blockSize;
        }
        while (blobLengthRemaining > 0);
    }
```

Comment: @Guarav Mantri... The memory stream gets disposed in the using statement, how do you download large files in segments and return the entire memory stream? I tried removing the using statement and adding a ms.Writeasync(blobContents) but ms is still empty when I return it