# download large file from azure blob storage using java/android with progress

Tags: android, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I am developing one android app where I need to download a file from the Azure blob I am able to download the file using the following code but I also want to show a progress bar while a file is downloading because it will be a large file say around 1/2 GB.

Gradle dependency:

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:2.0.0'
```

How I am downloading the file:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.getContainerReference("test");
Iterable blobs = container.listBlobs();
for (Object listBlobItem : blobs) {
     ListBlobItem blob = (ListBlobItem) listBlobItem;
     CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blob;
     // Downloading files from the container
     cloudBlob.downloadToFile(fileSample.getAbsolutePath());
     Log.e("INFO", "File downloaded");
 }
```

How can I achieve the download progress?

Comment: Try to use the `DownloadManager`, here's an example (not mine) : [AzureStorageExplorerAndroid](https://github.com/praneetloke/AzureStorageExplorerAndroid/blob/27306cd75151d4c4508d9d34599600265fcd9e70/app/src/main/java/com/pl/azurestorageexplorer/fragments/BlobListFragment.java)

Comment: Ok thanks will check

Answer (score 0):

The process in the [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763235/azure-download-blob-part) which  gives method to download Blobs  by splitting it into small size chunks which is refered in suggestion to this [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990239/azure-blob-storage-async-download-with-progress-bar) may give an idea on how to approach .

-Thanks to [@Gaurav mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri)

Other reference:  [Asynchronous-parallel-blob-transfers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kwill/asynchronous-parallel-blob-transfers-with-progress-change-notification-2-0#simple-console-client)