# download and split large file into 100 MB chunks in blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a 2GB file in blob storage and am building a console application that will download this file into a desktop. Requirement is to split into 100MB chunks and append a number into the filename. I do not need to re-combine those files again. What I need is only the chunks of files.

I currently have this code from [Azure download blob part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763235/azure-download-blob-part)

But I cannot figure out how to stop downloading when the file size is already 100MB and create a new one.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Update: Here is my code**

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            var file = uri;
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file);
            //First fetch the size of the blob. We use this to create an empty file with size = blob's size
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            var blobSize = blob.Properties.Length;
            long blockSize = (1 * 1024 * 1024);//1 MB chunk;
            blockSize = Math.Min(blobSize, blockSize);
            //Create an empty file of blob size
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))//Create empty file.
            {
                fs.SetLength(blobSize);//Set its size
            }
            var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
            {
                RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 3),
                MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
            };
            long startPosition = 0;
            long currentPointer = 0;
            long bytesRemaining = blobSize;
            do
            {
                var bytesToFetch = Math.Min(blockSize, bytesRemaining);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //Download range (by default 1 MB)
                    blob.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, currentPointer, bytesToFetch, null, blobRequestOptions);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    var contents = ms.ToArray();
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))//Open that file
                    {
                        fs.Position = currentPointer;//Move the cursor to the end of file.
                        fs.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);//Write the contents to the end of file.
                    }
                    startPosition += blockSize;
                    currentPointer += contents.Length;//Update pointer
                    bytesRemaining -= contents.Length;//Update bytes to fetch

                    Console.WriteLine(fileName + dateTimeStamp + ".csv " + (startPosition / 1024 / 1024) + "/" + (blob.Properties.Length / 1024 / 1024) + " MB downloaded...");
                }
            }
            while (bytesRemaining > 0);
```

Comment: just developed a Powershell script instead since this code has the tendency to "hang" when the file size is more than a gigabyte. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Per my understanding, you could break your blob file into your expected pieces (100MB), then leverage [CloudBlockBlob.DownloadRangeToStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadrangetostream(v=azure.10).aspx) to download each of your chunks of files. Here is my code snippet, you could refer to it:

**ParallelDownloadBlob**

```
private static void ParallelDownloadBlob(Stream outPutStream, CloudBlockBlob blob,long startRange,long endRange)
{
    blob.FetchAttributes();
    int bufferLength = 1 * 1024 * 1024;//1 MB chunk for download
    long blobRemainingLength = endRange-startRange;
    Queue<KeyValuePair<long, long>> queues = new Queue<KeyValuePair<long, long>>();
    long offset = startRange;
    while (blobRemainingLength > 0)
    {
        long chunkLength = (long)Math.Min(bufferLength, blobRemainingLength);
        queues.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<long, long>(offset, chunkLength));
        offset += chunkLength;
        blobRemainingLength -= chunkLength;
    }
    Parallel.ForEach(queues,
        new ParallelOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
        }, (queue) =>
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                blob.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, queue.Key, queue.Value);
                lock (outPutStream)
                {
                    outPutStream.Position = queue.Key- startRange;
                    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    outPutStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

**Program Main**

```
var container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(defaultContainerName);
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("code.txt");
blob.FetchAttributes();
long blobTotalLength = blob.Properties.Length;
long chunkLength = 10 * 1024; //divide blob file into each file with 10KB in size
for (long i = 0; i <= blobTotalLength; i += chunkLength)
{

    long startRange = i;
    long endRange = (i + chunkLength) > blobTotalLength ? blobTotalLength : (i + chunkLength);

    using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, $"resources\\code_[{startRange}]_[{endRange}].txt"), FileMode.Create))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nParallelDownloadBlob from range [{startRange}] to [{endRange}] start...");
        Stopwatch sp = new Stopwatch();
        sp.Start();

        ParallelDownloadBlob(fs, blob, startRange, endRange);
        sp.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"download done, time cost:{sp.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0}s");
    }
}
```

**RESULT**
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Based on your requirement, I recommend that you could download your blob into a single file, then leverage [LumenWorks.Framework.IO](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorks.Framework.IO/) to read your large file records line by line, then check the byte size you have read and save into a new csv file with the size up to 100MB. Here is a code snippet, you could refer to it:

```
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
{
    int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
    string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1};",
                          headers[i],
                          csv[i] == null ? "MISSING" : csv[i]));
        //TODO: 
        //1.Read the current record, check the total bytes you have read;
        //2.Create a new csv file if the current total bytes up to 100MB, then save the current record to the current CSV file.
    }
}
```

Additionally, you could refer to [A Fast CSV Reader](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) and [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) for more details.

**UPDATE2**

Code sample for breaking large CSV file into small CSV file with the fixed bytes, I used [CsvHelper 2.16.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) for the following code snippet, you could refer to it:

```
string[] headers = new string[0];
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\v-brucch\Desktop\BlobHourMetrics.csv")) //83.9KB
{
    using (CsvHelper.CsvReader csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(sr,
        new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration()
        {
            Delimiter = ",",
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        }))
    {
        //check header
        if (csvReader.ReadHeader())
        {
            headers = csvReader.FieldHeaders;
        }

        TextWriter writer = null;
        CsvWriter csvWriter = null;
        long readBytesCount = 0;
        long chunkSize = 30 * 1024; //divide CSV file into each CSV file with byte size up to 30KB

        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            var curRecord = csvReader.CurrentRecord;
            var curRecordByteCount = curRecord.Sum(r => Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(r)) + headers.Count() + 1;
            readBytesCount += curRecordByteCount;

            //check bytes you have read
            if (writer == null || readBytesCount > chunkSize)
            {
                readBytesCount = curRecordByteCount + headers.Sum(h => Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(h)) + headers.Count() + 1;
                if (writer != null)
                {
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
                }
                string fileName = $"BlobHourMetrics_{Guid.NewGuid()}.csv";
                writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName), true);
                csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer);
                csvWriter.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                //output header field
                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    csvWriter.WriteField(header);
                }
                csvWriter.NextRecord();
            }
            //output record field
            foreach (var field in curRecord)
            {
                csvWriter.WriteField(field);
            }
            csvWriter.NextRecord();
        }
        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT**[image]

Comment: Tried this. And it "breaks" the record on the last line of the file and continues on the next file. This should not be the case. E.g. on the last row, it writes on the first three columns out of seven then resumes writing the data in the next four columns in the first line of the next file.

Comment: As you described, split your blob file into fixed size, it would must break your records. Could you provide the structure of your blob records ?

Comment: table with seven columns. would be better if you have the complete snippet using lumenworks. :)

Comment: According to your requirement, I updated my answer, you could refer to it.

Comment: the parameter in your StreamReader is already in your local drive. What i need is download in chunks from blob storage without breaking the records. Hope this clears.

Comment: As you can see, when download from blob, we could check the byte count we have retrieved, but we could not determine which byte ranges could not break the record. So, I would suggest you download your blob file first, then break the large csv file into small chunk csv file.

Comment: Should I leverage Lumenworks in downloading the file from blob storage?

Comment: For downloading large blob files, I assumed that you could just refer to my `ParallelDownloadBlob` method for downloading your blob into a single csv file in parallel.