# PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response When down load with azure blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, reactor-netty

I try to download the large file from azure blob storage by these line of code:

```
            BlobClient blobAsyncClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString1)
                    .buildClient()
                    .getBlobContainerClient(blob)
                    .getBlobClient(client);
blobAsyncClient.downloadToFile(path);
```

And i got this exception:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations$PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:326)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:91)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1500)
    at com.azure.storage.common.implementation.StorageImplUtils.blockWithOptionalTimeout(StorageImplUtils.java:99)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.downloadToFileWithResponse(BlobClientBase.java:557)
    at com.gooddata.cloudresource.service.connection.BlobStorageDataSourceService.validateConnection(BlobStorageDataSourceService.java:89)
    at com.gooddata.cloudresource.model.worker.CloudConnectionValidationWorker.lambda$doProcessTask$1(CloudConnectionValidationWorker.java:55)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at com.gooddata.cloudresource.model.worker.CloudConnectionValidationWorker.doProcessTask(CloudConnectionValidationWorker.java:55)
    at com.gooddata.cloudresource.model.worker.CloudConnectionValidationWorker.doProcessTask(CloudConnectionValidationWorker.java:33)
    at com.gooddata.gcf.worker.AbstractWorker.processTask(AbstractWorker.java:27)
    at com.gooddata.gcf.http.TaskHolder.call(TaskHolder.java:52)
    at com.gooddata.gcf.http.TaskHolder.call(TaskHolder.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
```

After changing downloadToFileWithResponse with ParallelTransferOptions has block size is 0.5MB for each chunk some times its works.

Can someone help tell me why it happened?

Do we have any stable solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this [link](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/8584-a-note-on-azure-storage-and-downloading-large-files.html)

If you are downloading large file from Azure blob  you could try to use Shared Access Signature (SAS), or serve the file in chunk

To serve the file in chunk please check with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381097/download-and-split-large-file-into-100-mb-chunks-in-blob-storage)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm considering chunk size everything is fine with chunk size is : 0.5Mbs

Comment: Hi @duynguyễn, have you tried  using  latest spring-boot & reactor-netty version?

Comment: my application has some limitations so we depend on spring boots 2.1.4 closely