# How to read large csv from Azure container using Python Azure Function?

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I need to read a larger csv efficiently from container using Python Azure Function.

I am using the below code for reading csv, it works fine for small csv but there must be some other way to read larger csv efficiently.

```
# Container Connection.
container_client1 = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str=conn_str, 
    container_name=container_name
    )

# Reading File.
downloaded_blob = container_client.download_blob(file_name.csv)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(downloaded_blob.content_as_text()))
```

The Above function taking too much time to read ~2gb file.
I need help to efficiently read the larger csv using Python Azure Function.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is to process the file in chunks, resulting in lower memory use while parsing.

```py
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
```

**NOTE:-** `chunksize` parameter refers to number of rows per chunk.

Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381097/download-and-split-large-file-into-100-mb-chunks-in-blob-storage) that you can refer to.

**REFERENCES:**
[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)